# What important factors does this question still lack that should be added to to make it upto the mark?

Tags: discussion

[Which of the questions is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/which-of-the-questions-is-correct)

Till now, this question has got two TL votes and two down votes and only a single answer that too with no upvotes.

So I feel I should be worried now (the question was asked 7 hours ago) and ask here so that I can be clear on this issue.

So what are the matters that should be added more to make the question worthy of answers and of interest? Please anybody who has felt something has gone wrong are welcome to answer and suggest on this post.

**NB**- While I was typing this question up, Mohit made some comment and I changed the question accordingly and it can be seen in the [recent edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/1213/revisions). Have a look there and let me know if it further needs anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with the question is twofold: 1) It is very specific, which leans it toward the "too localized" category and 2) Even while being specific, it doesn't actually make clear what aspect of English you're trying to figure out.

I read your question several times when it appeared to me in the "review" tab with four close votes already attached.  After reading it thoroughly I couldn't figure out what you were asking, except (to simplify & paraphrase) "Is there anything wrong with these 4 sentences? If there is what is it?" Inherently this is a proofreading question, which I think (please correct me if I'm wrong) is not something we support in general.  If you had a specific question about each sentence, it would have been answerable--but you didn't seem to.

So (in my humble opinion) if you do have a specific question about any or all of the sentences you posted, beyond the general "is anything wrong with them", please do edit the question to reflect that and request it be reopened.  Feel free to comment here, I'd be glad to cast the first reopen vote in that case.  But in my opinion it seems that the question was localized proofreading.

Does that make sense?  I think I wrote circles around myself trying to answer your question ;)

Comment: I have explained the reasons why I think each of them is correct grammatically just under each of them. But tried to confirm it. Isn't that okay?

Comment: @Mistu4u Ah, I don't know...this kind of thing is hard to judge, and one of the things we definitely need to iron out in beta, so I'm glad you posted a question on meta :) I guess in my view, a question that basically says "I think this sentence is right.  Is it?" requires a yes or no answer, and a yes or no answer doesn't really fit the format of SE. (Though if the answer is 'no' I suppose you'd hope for a more detailed answer but--if you're right, all you'd get is confirmation & a "yes"). Upvoted for attention; maybe someone with a lot of SE-model experience can come weigh in!

Comment: Thank you for your participation. I find it hard as why people don't comment before down-vote/close vote so that OP in any question can understand their faults and can rectify themselves.

Comment: "I think this sentence is right. Is it?" had an implicit indication _even if it is correct, I am having doubts, please clarify that_. That's why the addition of _isn't it_.

Comment: @Mistu4u A similar discussion has now been raised here on meta, you may view it here if you like: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258/should-proofreading-questions-be-closed-as-offtopic